# How do I return usernames dynamically in query results when they are not current user?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a script working just fine below for returning and displaying results in a table (using mysql and wordpress), but I've arrived at a point I knew would be tricky when I got here. I can easily get the current user name but I don't know how to dynamically get the name of another user (NOT current user) from another table to display for a record. So I have a table "movies" and all the info is here except for usernames, which are storied in the users table. I do have a an ID column in movies which can connect to ID in users though. How can I connect this to display the user names for each record?

Example/to clarify: 
The query below will show all movies that a user watched and display in 3 columns. The 3rd column is for which user on this website watched the movie last. How to I pull that user's name from another table and echo it in the records returned for the query as done below for the other columns? See placeholder in code indicated by ??????

```
<?php 
global $wpdb;
?>
Movies : <?php
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM movies where movies.current = 1");

if ($results) {
echo '<table>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td><b>Movie Name</b></td>';
echo '<td><b>Genre</b></td>';
echo '<td><b>Last User on this Website to See</b></td>';
echo '</tr>';
foreach ($results as $row) {
// Each $row is a row from the query
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>' . $row->movie_name; '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row->genre; '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row-> ??? how get username (Not current user) from users table ?? '</td>';
echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a simple join query with your users table

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT m.*,u.username FROM movies m
join users u on(m.user_id = u.id)
 where m.current = 1");
```

and in loop you have user name in `$row->username`

Comment: Hmmm. Yes, a join, but something wrong with my syntax, likely at the select * part. I am now getting no results. I have never seen that structure ("select movies.*, users_username) before. Is that right or just your example?          Currently I am at: $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT movies.*, movies.name, movies.genre, wp_users.username FROM movies
FULL JOIN wp_users ON movies.ID=wp_users.ID where movies.active = 1");

Comment: Do I have to specify which variables (like movies.genre) or can I do something like this:  $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM movies LEFT JOIN ON movies.ID=wp_users.ID where movies.active = 1");